# Get the Div width without the scroll Bar width

Tags: javascript, jquery, width, scrollbar

I am having a issue here. There are two div's here "div1" and "div2". Here I want to adjust the "div1" width according to the "div2" width. My requirement is The width of the scrollBar should not be included for the "div1" i.e i should set the height of the "div1"
excluding the width of the scrollBar in "div2". I want a jquery function to find the width and to reduce the width of "div1"..
Sample requirement is shown below

### html

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2">HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello</div>
```

### css

```
.div1
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.div2
{
    width:100px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow:auto;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

[image]

The Fiddle Demo is here

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d34Fk/)

Comment: try this - http://jsfiddle.net/d34Fk/1/

Comment: i am expecting a jquery function to dynamically reduce the width, it should not be hard coded

Comment: ok now try - http://jsfiddle.net/d34Fk/3/

Comment: K.. Here the scroll Width is hard coded. Anyway to get the scroll-Bar width dynamically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/d34Fk/5/

jQuery :

```
var width = $('.div2')[0]['clientWidth'];
$('.div1').css({'width':width+'px'});
```

Comment: That's great! but can u explain wat's clientwidth...?

Comment: console.log($('.div2')) gives you all information about that particular DOM element. clientWidth is width without scrollbar. Open this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/d34Fk/10/ , than open Developer Tools and navigate to Console. you will see there your logged element. Navigate to 0, and search clientWidth, information is all there.